# Finding the cells that contain the \N value and replacing them with 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big dataframe and when I process it I receive this error

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: \N

To get rid of this error I need to replace the \N values with 0. I tried this code:

```
set1[set1 == '\N'] = 0 
#This also did not work --> set1[set1.ix[:,:] == '\N'] = 0
```

But, then I receive this error:

> TypeError: Could not compare ['\N'] with block values

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set1 = map(lambda val: val if type(val) is str else 0, set1)
```

Assuming `set1` is a list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use for comprehensions.

```
set1 = [item if item != '\N' else 0 for item in set1]
```

(as with the other answer, this turns 'set1' into a Python `list` object; if it's something else and you want it to stay that way, this won't do the trick).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!